# iOS Full Screen Camera with AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, video-capture, avcapturesession

i am useing **AVCaptureSession** for recording video, when i set **SessionPreset** to Meduim camera does not appeare on the whole area , mean its left empty spcae from top and bottom. iattached the sample screen shot, is there any way to show cam to full screen/ fill the whole screen with **AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium**.!

[image: ScreenShot of current view with AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium]

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: i am using Apple sample code here is link (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Objective_C_AVCam_main_m.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to have full screen using `AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium`.
I guess it's related to the fact that `AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium` won't give you very high quality so you can't get a full screen image while having a medium quality.

If you really need to have the camera full screen, switch to `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`.